# PySpark Window Function Null handling

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to handle null values using window function in pyspark==3.2.0.

The raw data in csv format is:

```text
key1,key2,client_id,event_timestamp
1D7B****-****-****-****-******EC1E09,,9397****-****-****-****-******BFACBB,2021-02-25T16:04:12.391Z
1D7B****-****-****-****-******EC1E09,AE8D****-****-****-****-******3E7E75,9397****-****-****-****-******BFACBB,2021-02-25T02:15:44.587Z
1D7B****-****-****-****-******EC1E09,,9397****-****-****-****-******BFACBB,2021-02-25T02:19:59.084Z
1D7B****-****-****-****-******EC1E09,,9397****-****-****-****-******BFACBB,2021-02-25T02:31:07.170Z
```

I have to get the last `key2` and `client_id` based on `key1` and `event_timestamp`. The current pyspark code I wrote is:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

sc = SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("test run")
    .getOrCreate()

df = sc.read.csv('my-csv.csv')

df.select(
    F.col('key1'),
    F.last('key2', False).over(
        Window.partitionBy('key1').orderBy(F.col('event_timestamp').desc())
    ).alias('last_key2'),
    F.last('client_id', False).over(
        Window.partitionBy('key1').orderBy(F.col('event_timestamp').desc())
    ).alias('last_client_id')
)
```

But the result return 2 rows of data - one for `key2` is null and one for `key2` is non-null.

```text
key1,last_key2,last_client_id
1D7B****-****-****-****-******EC1E09,null,9397****-****-****-****-******BFACBB
1D7B****-****-****-****-******EC1E09,AE8D****-****-****-****-******3E7E75,9397****-****-****-****-******BFACBB
```

The expected result is here because the `last_key2` is null if we look carefully.

```text
key1,last_key2,last_client_id
1D7B****-****-****-****-******EC1E09,null,9397****-****-****-****-******BFACBB
```

Why Spark returns 2 rows if I use window function partitioned by `key1`? How can I write my code so that I can get my expected result?

Comment: Do you want to select the row having the highest `event_timestamp` for each `key1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ordering the Window in `descending` but using `last` function that's why you get the non-null value of `key2`. [`last`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.last.html) function gives you the last value in frame of window according to your ordering. What you want to use here is [`first`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.first.html) function or change the ordering to `ascending`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

w = Window.partitionBy('key1').orderBy(F.col('event_timestamp').desc())

df.select(
    F.col('key1'),
    F.first('key2', ignorenulls=False).over(w).alias('last_key2'),
    F.first('client_id', ignorenulls=False).over(w).alias('last_client_id')
).show(truncate=False)
```

Note that using a Window like this will will always return multiple rows for each `key1` as there is no grouping by or filtering. You'll need to add `distinct()` after select.

---

That being said, for this case, you can simply use `row_number` over the same window spec you defined and then rename the columns `key2` and  `client_id` respectively to `last_key2` and `last_client_id`:

```py
df.withColumn(
    "rn",
    F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('key1').orderBy(F.col('event_timestamp').desc()))
).filter("rn = 1").select(
    F.col('key1'),
    F.col('key2').alias("last_key2"),
    F.col('client_id').alias("last_client_id")
).show(truncate=False)

#+------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+
#|key1                                |last_key2|last_client_id                      |
#+------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+
#|1D7B****-****-****-****-******EC1E09|null     |9397****-****-****-****-******BFACBB|
#+------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+
```